# Devise user profile setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Need to ensure that all my users each have a profile once they sign up (devise) to my rails application but not sure how to execute this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create their user accounts just create their profile. The profile belongs to the account. The account has one profile.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  # choose a call back or overwrite the create
  after_create :add_profile

  private
  def add_profile
    self.profile = Profile.create
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Something like that.

Comment: cool. What about the view for the profile? profile.html.erb? or should I scaffold profile?

Comment: no scaffolding! :-) the view would be `app/views/profiles/show.html.erb`. I would recommend you do this tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) a few times (5+) to get the basic idea.

Comment: Your right, I sure will! How would I obtain the profile model then? **rails generate model profile example1:string example2:string** ?

Comment: yes, for models use a generator. for controllers generators are okay too, but scaffolding (`rails generate scaffold Something`) is too much.

Comment: Managed to find my way. Thanks a lot